# How to rank a BigQuery table based on the upper & lower bounds of a value's margin of error in each row

Tags: google-bigquery, ranking

I've got a BigQuery table of percentages & the associated margin of error on each of those percentages. Is there a way in BigQuery Standard SQL to use or replicate the `RANK()` function to determine the numbering of that table for the range of values the margin of error represents? For example, if I have:

```
WITH `test_data` AS (
  SELECT 'A' Name, 91.4 Percentage, 0.9 Percentage_Error UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 90.5, 0.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 89.9, 0.7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 88.8, 0.3
)
SELECT
  Name,
  Percentage,
  Percentage_Error,
  Percentage + Percentage_Error AS UpperBound,
  Percentage - Percentage_Error AS LowerBound,
  /* 1 AS Uncalculated_Rank */
FROM
  `test_data`
```

I'd like the ranking to:

- consider anything with an `UpperBound` lower then a `LowerBound` as peer rows to receive the same rank value
- make the next rank value incremented by the number of peers with the previous rank value

So in this example, my results would be:

| Entry | Percentage | Percentage_Error | UpperBound | LowerBound | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 91.4 | 0.9 | 92.3 | 90.5 | 1 |
| B | 90.5 | 0.5 | 91.0 | 90.0 | 1 |
| C | 89.9 | 0.7 | 90.6 | 89.2 | 1 |
| D | 88.8 | 0.3 | 89.1 | 88.5 | 4 |

If it helps, I had previously implemented a form of this ranking in Javascript; the logic was such for an array of objects `values` where `ranking` was initially set to `1` for all entries & it was sorted in descending order by `percentage`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
    if (values[i].lowerBound > values[j].upperBound) {
      values[j].ranking += 1;
    }
  }
                
  if (i != 0 && values[i - 1].ranking != values[i].ranking && values[i].ranking < i + 1) {
    values[i].ranking = i + 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, your example is a bit vague, I'd like to see more cases to understand it better. As far as I understand, you want to cross join the table to itself, but only for the rows to the below.

The query below gives the output you want, but I'm not sure if it's what you want.

```
WITH 
test_data AS 
(
  SELECT 'A' Name, 91.4 Percentage, 0.9 Percentage_Error UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 90.5, 0.5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 89.9, 0.7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 88.8, 0.3
),
bounds as 
(
  SELECT
    Name,
    Percentage,
    Percentage_Error,
    Percentage + Percentage_Error AS UpperBound,
    Percentage - Percentage_Error AS LowerBound,
    row_number() over (order by Name) as rank1
  FROM test_data
)
select 
  b1.Name,
  any_value(b1.Percentage) as Percentage,
  any_value(b1.Percentage_Error) as Percentage_Error,
  any_value(b1.UpperBound) as UpperBound,
  any_value(b1.LowerBound) as LowerBound,
  countif(b1.UpperBound < b2.LowerBound) + 1 as Rank
from bounds b1
left join bounds b2
  on b1.rank1 > b2.rank1
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this implementation; I believe it does do what I want! I was beginning to look into `CROSS JOIN`  as a way to compare all the values like my Javascript implementation, but wasn't sure how to limit it to the rows 'below'. If you're interested in iterating on it further, I can provide more example data/results, but this seems to handle the cases I need!